# fatal error while unwrapping a view controller value

Tags: ios, swift

I have a few viewcontrollers in storyboard with certain identifiers and when I try to access them like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let mainViewController = sideMenuController!
    let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
    let viewController: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
    let navigationController = mainViewController.rootViewController as! NavigationController
    navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    mainViewController.hideLeftView(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)

}
```

The app crashes. This line is detecting that the value is nil. Can anyone explain how this is nil while unwrapping?

```
navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

After several attempts I managed to get rid off the fatal error. However the view controller  still does not appear upon tapping on the table view item.

- Original Project -
  [link](https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGSideMenuController/tree/master/Demo_Swift)
- Edited Project -
  [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4ZxpaK_rotKRW5kRDBadmtBbEk)

Comment: you havent unwrapped it you just stated the UIViewController will not be nil you need to put the ! on the end of storyboard?. instantiateViewController(name)!

Comment: Probably `storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)` returns `nil`.

Comment: @SeanLintern88 I can't force unwrap a non optional type.

Comment: @shallowThought why would it return nil ? All the view controllers are assigned with correct storyboard indetifiers.

Comment: Are you sure the storyboard is not nil?

Comment: @BjørnRuthberg  yup.

Comment: What is nil in the line that crashes? NavigationController or viewcontroller?

Comment: @BjørnRuthberg viewcontroller. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Either `storyboard?` is `nil` or  `vcName` does not fit the identifier set in Storyboard. Make sure you did not accidentally add a leading/trailing space. Also show how you get `storyboard`.

Comment: `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)`

Comment: I just downloaded the github repository. Can you exactly say how to reproduce? I tried Demo_Swift_Storyboard and Demo_Swift, but I cannot find any problem here...

Comment: @Andreas Oetjen This is the modified code - [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ZxpaK_rotKTDRpLVJjcXdoNXM/view?usp=sharing) , this is after a few things I've tried. I just need to make the view controller with identifier "A" to appear .

Comment: @Rakshith: The project doesn't compile, file MainViewController.swift is missing.

Comment: Don't force unwrap`!`

Comment: @AndreasOetjen sorry, check this one - [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4ZxpaK_rotKRW5kRDBadmtBbEk)

Comment: @Rakshith, please clean up your project, it's not quite good compilable.
Running it, I get the following error:
`LGSideMenuControllerDemo[39585:926695] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x638000066600>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'D''`
And indeed, there is no such view controller in the Main.storyboard.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen  that's fine. It was written to only work with 'A'. So when tapped on engine tunning parameters it has to load that view controller.

Comment: @Rakshith, I'll write an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the project is a little "messed up" :-)

**First**: You need to somehow get "the" `UINavigationController` (or derived class).

Since your `LeftViewController` is not on the navigation stack, it does not have a navigationController set. So, you need to get it from the `mainViewController`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    print(storyboard)
    let mainViewController = sideMenuController!
    let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
    let viewController: UIViewController! = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
    print(viewController)
    if let theNavigationController = mainViewController.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
        print("Gotcha")
        theNavigationController.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
        mainViewController.hideLeftView(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
    }

}
```

**Second**, there is still a problem:

The view controller with identifier 'A' is of type `EngineTunningParamteres`, derived from `UINavigationController`. You cannot push a navigation controller onto an existing navigation controller. Therefore, we have to change the class, too:

```
class EngineTunningParamteres: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("hi")    }

}
```

Now it works. You're welcome.

Comment: Thank you so much. Eventhough the topic diverted from fatal error you helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
let viewController: UIViewController!
```

is an `Optional`, with this `!` you are just telling the compiler "I know this may be nil but don't worry, at run time it will never be nil".

If you want to get rid of this `Optional` you have to unwrap the storyboard :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let mainViewController = sideMenuController!
    let vcName = identities[indexPath.row]
    let viewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcName)
    let navigationController = mainViewController.rootViewController as! NavigationController
    navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    mainViewController.hideLeftView(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)

}
```